# What is a Cursor in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-cursor

We are troubled by eventually occurring `cursor not found exceptions` for some Morphia Queries [`asList`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/querying/) and I've found a [hint on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201116/2092322), that this might be quite memory consumptive.

Now I'd like to know a bit more about the background: can sombody explain (in English), what a Cursor (in MongoDB) actually is? Why can it kept open or be not found?

---

The documentation [defines](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) a cursor as:

> A pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a cursor to retrieve results. By default, cursors timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity

But this is not very telling. Maybe it could be helpful to define a `batch` for query results, because the [documentation also states](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#read-operations-cursors):

> The MongoDB server returns the query results in batches. Batch size will not exceed the maximum BSON document size. For most queries, the first batch returns 101 documents or just enough documents to exceed 1 megabyte. Subsequent batch size is 4 megabytes. [...] For queries that include a sort operation without an index, the server must load all the documents in memory to perform the sort before returning any results.

Note: in our queries in question we don't use sort statements at all, but also no `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: I feel that your question is wandering off the topic you should be asking about. If you are indeed receiving *"cursor not found"* exceptions, then issue at fault will be your implemented code. A wider discussion of what a cursor "actually is" is more of a "broader design question" than something that solves an specific programming problem, such as what this site is for, Therefore *"too much ranting about cursors, and not enough code that could be causing the issue"*. As it stands, your question looks like it's asking for a thesis explaining what a cursor is. Just show some code.

Comment: The point is, that the occurrence of these exceptions depends on the environment. We currently don't know, which parameter (memory, CPU, whatever) is the crucial one. Therefore I'm interested in some **background**. Our code looks like `ds.find(Translation.class).asList()` (ds is a Morphia.Datastrore).

Comment: If you run mongo in a replica set the cursor will be lost if your servers decides on another primary node.

Comment: @froderik You are so true. You need a `seed list` of servers, never use your own load balancing solution. [Description here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-discovery-and-monitoring-next-generation-mongodb-drivers).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am by no mean a mongodb expert but I just want to add some observations from working in a medium sized mongo system for the last year. Also thanks to @xameeramir for the excellent walkthough about how cursors work in general.

The causes of a "cursor lost" exception may be several. One that I have noticed is explained in this answer.

The cursor lives server side. It is not distributed over a replica set but exists on the instance that is primary at the time of creation. This means that if another instance takes over as primary the cursor will be lost to the client. If the old primary is still up and around it may still be there but for no use. I guess it is garbaged collected away after a while. So if your mongo replica set is unstable or you have a shaky network in front of it you are out of luck when doing any long running queries.

If the full content of what the cursor wants to return does not fit in memory on the server the query may be very slow. RAM on your servers needs to be larger than the largest query you run.

All this can partly be avoided by designing better. For a use case with large long running queries you may be better of with several smaller database collections instead of a big one.

Answer (score 67):

Here's a comparison between `toArray()` and cursors after a `find()` in the Node.js MongoDB driver. Common code:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
assert = require('assert');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crunchbase', function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB.');

    const query = { category_code: "biotech" };

    // toArray() vs. cursor code goes here
});
```

Here's the [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray) code that goes in the section above.

```js
    db.collection('companies').find(query).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.notEqual(docs.length, 0);

        docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(`${doc.name} is a ${doc.category_code} company.`);
        });

        db.close();
    });
```

Per the documentation,

> The caller is responsible for making sure that there
>   is enough memory to store the results.

Here's the cursor-based approach, using the [`cursor.forEach()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach) method:

```js
    const cursor = db.collection('companies').find(query);

    cursor.forEach(
        function (doc) {
            console.log(`${doc.name} is a ${doc.category_code} company.`);
        },
        function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            return db.close();
        }
    );
});
```

With the `forEach()` approach, instead of fetching all data in memory, we're streaming the data to our application. `find()` creates a cursor immediately because it doesn't actually make a request to the database until we try to use some of the documents it will provide. The point of `cursor` is to describe our query. The second parameter to `cursor.forEach` shows what to do when an error occurs.

In the initial version of the above code, it was `toArray()` which forced the database call. It meant we needed **ALL** the documents and wanted them to be in an `array`.

Note that `MongoDB` returns data in batches. The image below shows requests from cursors (from application) to `MongoDB`:

[image: MongoDB cursor graphic]

`forEach` scales better than `toArray` because we can process documents **as they come in** until we reach the end. Contrast it with `toArray` - where we wait for **ALL** the documents to be retrieved and the **entire** array is built. This means we're not getting any advantage from the fact that the driver and the database system are working together to batch results to your application. Batching is meant to provide efficiency in terms of memory overhead and the execution time. *Take advantage of it in your application, if you can.*

Comment: The answer seems to be slightly outdated as `toArray()` now doesn't take any parameters (do they call this a "deferred" in JS?), but returns a Promise instead. The difference between `toArray` and Cursors holds though.

Answer (score 11):

The collection's `find` method returns a *cursor* - this points to the set of documents (called as *result set*) that are matched to the query filter. The result set is the actual documents that are returned by the query, but this is on the database server.

To the client program, for example the `mongo` shell, you get a cursor. You can think the cursor is like an API or a program to work with the result set. The cursor has many methods which can be run to perform some actions on the result set. Some of the methods affect the result set data and some provide the status or info about the result set.

As the cursor maintains information about the result set, some information can change as you use the result set data by applying other cursor methods. You use these methods and information to suit your application, i.e., how and what you want to do with the queried data.

**Working on the result set using the cursor and some of its commonly used methods and features from `mongo` shell:**

The `count()` method returns the ***count*** of the number of documents in the result set, initially - as the result of the query. It is always constant at any point in the life of the cursor. This is information. This information remains same even after the cursor is closed or exhausted.

As you read documents from the result set, the result set gets exhausted. Once completely exhausted you cannot read any more. The `hasNext()` tells if there are any documents available to be read - returns a boolean true or false. The `next()` returns a document if available (you first check with `hasNext`, and then do a `next`). These two methods are commonly used to ***iterate*** over the result set data. Another iteration method is the `forEach()`.

The data is retrieved from the server in ***batches*** - which has a default size. With the first batch you read the documents and when all it's documents are read, the following `next()` method retrieves the next batch of documents, etc., until all documents are read from the result set. This batch size can be configured and you can also get its status.

If you apply the `toArray()` method on the cursor, then all the remaining documents in the result set are loaded into the memory of your client computer and are available as a JavaScript ***array***. And, the result set data is exhausted. The following `hasNext` method will return `false`, and the `next` will throw an error (once you exhaust the cursor, you cannot read data from it). This method loads all the result set data into your client's memory (the array). This can be memory consuming in case of large result sets.

The `itcount()` returns the ***count*** of remaining documents in the result set and exhausts the cursor.

There are cursor methods like `isClosed()`, `isExhausted()`, `size()` which give ***status*** information about the cursor and its underlying result set as you work with your data.

Those are the basic features of cursor and result set. There are many cursor methods, and you can try and see how they work and get a better understanding.

***Reference***:

- [mongo shell's cursor
  methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)
- [Cursor behavior with Aggregate
  method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#cursor-behavior)
  (the collection's `aggregate` method also returns a cursor)

**Example usage in `mongo` shell:**

Assume the `test` collection has 200 documents (run the commands in the same sequence).

- `var cur = db.test.find( { } ).limit(25)` creates a result set with 25
  documents only.
- But, `cur.count()` will show 200, which is the actual count of
  documents by the query's filter.
- `hasNext()` will return `true`.
- `next()` will return a document.
- `itcount()` will return 24 (and exhausts the cursor).
- `itcount()` again will return 0.
- `cur.count()` will still show 200.

Comment: This was really helpful. Does this mean that if I get a cursor from a .find operation, get a count from the cursor, do some deletes on said collection, and run the count again... the result of the count will remain the same, right?

Comment: See this post for some clarifications: [Cursor Isolation in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449882/cursor-isolation-in-mongodb). Also, see the [FAQ: Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/).

Answer (score 4):

This error also comes when you have a large set of data and are doing batch processing on that data and each batch takes more time, totalling that time be exceeded the default cursor live time.

Then you need to change that default time to tell mongo that will not expire this cursor until processing is done.

Do check [No TimeOut Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/)

Answer (score 1):

A cursor is an object returned by calling `db.collection.find()` and which enables iterating through documents (NoSQL equivalent of a SQL "row") of a MongoDB collection (NoSQL equivalent of "table").

Answer (score 0):

In case your cluster is stable and no members where down or changing state, the most posible reason for not finding the cursor is this:

Default idle cursor timeout is 10min  , but in the versions >= 3.6  the cursor is also associated with session which is having default session timeout 30min , so even you set the cursor to not expire with the option noCursorTimeout() you are still limited by the session timeout of 30min. To avoid your cursor to be killed by the session timeout you will need to perioducally check in your code and execute sessionRefresh command:

```
   db.adminCommand({"refreshSessions" : [sessionId]})
```

to extend the session with another 30min so your cursor to not be killed if you do something with the data before fetching the next batch...
check the docs here for detail how to do it:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/