# In find() function

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we do (in java):

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
```

where collection refers to a MongoDB Collection.

Are all the documents copied by value to the cursor at once or does the "cursor" just point to the collection and retrieve documents (one by one) as and when we declare a DBObject and find the corresponding value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766956/what-is-a-cursor-in-mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Cursor in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766956/what-is-a-cursor-in-mongodb)