# Why aggregate two collections with $out never ends ? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, mongodb4.0

OK, so, I have two collections. One of them has 6M documents, the other one has 25M documents. I want them in a new collection:

Collection 1 example:

Movie

```
 {"movieId" : "1", "name" : "Titanic"},
 {"movieId" : "2", "name" : "King Kong"}
```

Collection 2 example:

Character

```
{"characterId": "1", "movieId": "1", "characterName": "Name 1"},
{"characterId": "2", "movieId": "1", "characterName": "Name 2"},
{"characterId": "3", "movieId": "1", "characterName": "Name 3"}
```

So I want a new collection like:

```
{
  "movieId" : "1", 
  "name" : "Titanic", 
  "characters":[ *collection 2 here* ]
},
{
  "movieId" : "2", 
  "name" : "King Kong", 
  "characters":[]
}
```

I tried:

```
db.Movie.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "Character",localField: "movieId", foreignField: "movieId", as: "characters" }},{ $out : "movie_characters" }])
```

But it never ends :(  (by never I mean like 10 hours later it was still thinking) If I execute it without the $out it show results in 10 minutes maybe.

Am I doing something wrong with $out?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: which collection has 25M documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major thing you leaving here is an index.

`$lookup` when matching the foreign field, MongoDB uses the index.

So, create an index in the Character collection using:

```
db.Character.createIndex({ "movieId": 1 })
```

And then apply the lookup aggregation

```
db.Movie.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Character",
      localField: "movieId", 
      foreignField: "movieId", 
      as: "characters" 
    }
  },
  { 
    $out : "movie_characters" 
  }
])
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem not just in a single `index` but in performance also. I highly recommend you to use [Cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) for heavy queries like yours. ([Check this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766956/what-is-a-cursor-in-mongodb))

When you are using this query you also "flooding" your RAM with all the documents. So using cursor will definitely helps you.

Also, try to use [Mongo Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) for testing your queries before launch it on production via `Explain` mode, which gives your all what youneed to know, especially how long your query takes to execute, what indexes it using, and much more.

Comment: Thanks, Vijay Rajpurohit solved it, but I'm reading the doc you send for futures references. Have a nice day :) and thanks for your time